# Как сделать ограничение размера данных или фильтрацию сообщений , которые приходят на сокет клиента TCP в Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, сокет, tcp

Подскажите, как сделать так чтобы можно было ограничить размер данных, которые приходят на порт TCP сокета клиента? Т.е. ввести ограниичения размер принимаемых сообщений и отбрасывать их, или выводить их в отдельные объекты, чтобы работать с ними отдельно.

Объясню для чего это надо: Я работаю с промышленным ПО. ОТ ПО в виде сервера приходит XML строка. Я должен ее парсить и далее с ней работать, но проблема в том, что на порт приходит не только данные XML, но еще несколько символов непонятного назначения и формата (прим:  M   ). 
Эти символы приходят, как отдельное сообщение от XML. Сокет естественно первым делом сначала их передает парсеру, а тот ругается. И дальше ошибки ничего не проходит.

Эти первые символы, которые приходят отдельно, возможно имеют какое-то скрытое и сакральное назначение, но мне они не нужны. Их всего три, притом первый символ читается и вторые два нет. Но даже если я их удалю (что странно, когда они попадают на мою функцию strClear, они идут как единое целое с XML данными ), парсер все равно каким-то образом читает какой-то символ, который даже в терминале IDLE не отображается.

Пример кода, который принимает и парсит сообщения:

```
import socket
import io
import lxml.etree
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def strClear(data):
    data = data.decode('windows-1251')
    number_first = data.find('<')  # Поиск "<", как точка отсчета
    data = data[number_first:]  # Делаем срез от точки отсчета до конца строки
    # new_data = re.sub(r'(</.+?>)', r'\1\n', data)  # Используем регулярку,
    # которая заменит закрывающий тег на него же  и добавит \n
    print(data)
    return data.encode()


addr = '127.0.0.1'
port = 5555
sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect((addr, port))
print('Connected by', addr, port)

sock.settimeout(None)

while True:
    data = sock.recv(524288)  # читает данные из сокета.
    udata = strClear(data)  # Декодирует данные из сокета
    open('log.txt', 'wb').write((data))
    open('log_2.txt', 'w').write(repr(data))
    # Вызывает функцию, которая преобразует строку добавляя в нее "перенос строки" \n
    print("Received data: \n", len(udata))
    if not data:
        print('No data')
        break
    input_data = io.BytesIO(udata)
    contents = input_data.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'lxml')
    print(soup.select_one('Acknowledge').text)

sock.close()  # Закрывает сокет.
```

Пример XML данных с которыми я работаю, в чистом сыром виде:

```
M<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251" ?><ROOT><elem><Acknowledged>1</Acknowledged><Active>0</Active><Actual>0</Actual><ID>1</ID><Text>                  </Text><Time>13178817729084.0000000000000</Time></elem><elem><Acknowledged>0</Acknowledged><Active>0</Active><Actual>0</Actual><ID>2</ID><Text>Target Manager -
/Text><Time>13178817743617.0000000000000</Time></elem><elem><Acknowledged>0</Acknowledged><Active>0</Active><Actual>0</Actual><ID>3</ID><Text>                            </Text><Time>13178817745794.0000000000000</Time></elem><elem><Acknowledged>1</Acknowledged><Active>0</Active><Actual>0</Actual><ID>4</ID><Text>└ЁсшЄЁ юЄёюхфшэхэ</Text><Time>13178817747156.0000000000000</Time></elem><elem><Acknowledged>1</Acknowledged><Active>0</Active><Actual>0</Actual><ID>9</ID><Text>└ЁсшЄЁ яюфёюхфшэхэ</Text><Time>13178817751471.0000000000000</Time></elem><elem><Acknowledged>1</Acknowledged><Active>0</Active><Actual>1</Actual><ID>8</ID><Text>╨рфрЁэ√х яЁюЎхёёюЁ√: test - эхЄ ёхЄхтюую ёюхфшэхэш/Text><Time>13178817751115.0000000000000</Time></elem></ROOT╙<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251" ?><ROOT><Acknowledged>1</Acknowledged><Active>0</Active><Actual>0</Actual><ID>11</ID><Text>                 </Text><Time>13178824977250.0000000000000</Time></ROOT>9<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251" ?><ROOT/>
```

В итоге получается, что сперва на сокет приходит:

M

А затем  тело XML данных.
Даже если я уберу эти первые символы из строки своей функцией `strClear(data)` , то все равно будет какой-то непонятноый нулевой символ, который и воспринимает парсер, хотя в терминале не отображается. Что в итоге приводит к ошибке.

Добавил в код вывод данных которые приходят в текстовый файл. И вот что получил, при работающем парсере:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А это уже при отключенном парсере:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это скриншот терминала IDE. Тут можно увидеть что несколько сообщений идет, и между ними вот эти непонятные символы, как отделные сообщения от которых нужно избавиться.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь я вообще отключил редактирование строки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скопировал XML с Notepad++:

```
M <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251" ?><ROOT><elem><Acknowledged>1</Acknowledged><Active>0</Active><Actual>0</Actual><ID>1</ID><Text>Арбитр подсоединен</Text><Time>13178888156476.0000000000000</Time></elem><elem><Acknowledged>0</Acknowledged><Active>0</Active><Actual>0</Actual><ID>2</ID><Text> нет сетевого соединения</Text><Time>13178888184672.0000000000000</Time></elem><elem><Acknowledged>0</Acknowledged><Active>0</Active><Actual>0</Actual><ID>3</ID><Text>Процессор системы перегружен</Text><Time>13178888191569.0000000000000</Time></elem><elem><Acknowledged>1</Acknowledged><Active>0</Active><Actual>0</Actual><ID>4</ID><Text>Арбитр отсоединен</Text><Time>13178888193208.0000000000000</Time></elem><elem><Acknowledged>1</Acknowledged><Active>0</Active><Actual>0</Actual><ID>6</ID><Text>Арбитр подсоединен</Text><Time>13178888194173.0000000000000</Time></elem><elem><Acknowledged>1</Acknowledged><Active>0</Active><Actual>1</Actual><ID>7</ID><Text>Радарные процессоры: test - нет сетевого соединения</Text><Time>13178888198029.0000000000000</Time></elem></ROOT>
```

Прикладываю содержимое log_2 (добавил в код создание лога, см. выше):

```
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251" ?><ROOT><elem><Acknowledged>1</Acknowledged><Active>0</Active><Actual>0</Actual><ID>1</ID><Text>\xc0\xf0\xe1\xe8\xf2\xf0 \xef\xee\xe4\xf1\xee\xe5\xe4\xe8\xed\xe5\xed</Text><Time>13178895874211.0000000000000</Time></elem><elem><Acknowledged>0</Acknowledged><Active>0</Active><Actual>0</Actual><ID>2</ID><Text> - \xed\xe5\xf2 \xf1\xe5\xf2\xe5\xe2\xee\xe3\xee \xf1\xee\xe5\xe4\xe8\xed\xe5\xed\xe8\xff</Text><Time>13178895889439.0000000000000</Time></elem><elem><Acknowledged>1</Acknowledged><Active>0</Active><Actual>0</Actual><ID>3</ID><Text>\xc0\xf0\xe1\xe8\xf2\xf0 \xee\xf2\xf1\xee\xe5\xe4\xe8\xed\xe5\xed</Text><Time>13178895892917.0000000000000</Time></elem><elem><Acknowledged>1</Acknowledged><Active>0</Active><Actual>0</Actual><ID>8</ID><Text>\xc0\xf0\xe1\xe8\xf2\xf0 \xef\xee\xe4\xf1\xee\xe5\xe4\xe8\xed\xe5\xed</Text><Time>13178895897239.0000000000000</Time></elem><elem><Acknowledged>1</Acknowledged><Active>0</Active><Actual>1</Actual><ID>7</ID><Text>\xd0\xe0\xe4\xe0\xf0\xed\xfb\xe5 \xef\xf0\xee\xf6\xe5\xf1\xf1\xee\xf0\xfb: test - \xed\xe5\xf2 \xf1\xe5\xf2\xe5\xe2\xee\xe3\xee \xf1\xee\xe5\xe4\xe8\xed\xe5\xed\xe8\xff</Text><Time>13178895896858.0000000000000</Time></elem></ROOT>'
```

Содержимое log_2 в HEX формате:

```
62273C3F786D6C2076657273696F6E3D
22312E302220656E636F64696E673D22
77696E646F77732D3132353122203F3E
3C524F4F543E3C656C656D3E3C41636B
6E6F776C65646765643E313C2F41636B
6E6F776C65646765643E3C4163746976
653E303C2F4163746976653E3C416374
75616C3E303C2F41637475616C3E3C49
443E313C2F49443E3C546578743E5C78
63305C7866305C7865315C7865385C78
66325C786630205C7865665C7865655C
7865345C7866315C7865655C7865355C
7865345C7865385C7865645C7865355C
7865643C2F546578743E3C54696D653E
31333137383839353837343231312E30
3030303030303030303030303C2F5469
6D653E3C2F656C656D3E3C656C656D3E
3C41636B6E6F776C65646765643E303C
2F41636B6E6F776C65646765643E3C41
63746976653E303C2F4163746976653E
3C41637475616C3E303C2F4163747561
6C3E3C49443E323C2F49443E3C546578
743E5472616E73617320546172676574
204D616E61676572202D205C7865645C
7865355C786632205C7866315C786535
5C7866325C7865355C7865325C786565
5C7865335C786565205C7866315C7865
655C7865355C7865345C7865385C7865
645C7865355C7865645C7865385C7866
663C2F546578743E3C54696D653E3133
3137383839353838393433392E303030
303030303030303030303C2F54696D65
3E3C2F656C656D3E3C656C656D3E3C41
636B6E6F776C65646765643E313C2F41
636B6E6F776C65646765643E3C416374
6976653E303C2F4163746976653E3C41
637475616C3E303C2F41637475616C3E
3C49443E333C2F49443E3C546578743E
5C7863305C7866305C7865315C786538
5C7866325C786630205C7865655C7866
325C7866315C7865655C7865355C7865
345C7865385C7865645C7865355C7865
643C2F546578743E3C54696D653E3133
3137383839353839323931372E303030
303030303030303030303C2F54696D65
3E3C2F656C656D3E3C656C656D3E3C41
636B6E6F776C65646765643E313C2F41
636B6E6F776C65646765643E3C416374
6976653E303C2F4163746976653E3C41
637475616C3E303C2F41637475616C3E
3C49443E383C2F49443E3C546578743E
5C7863305C7866305C7865315C786538
5C7866325C786630205C7865665C7865
655C7865345C7866315C7865655C7865
355C7865345C7865385C7865645C7865
355C7865643C2F546578743E3C54696D
653E3133313738383935383937323339
2E303030303030303030303030303C2F
54696D653E3C2F656C656D3E3C656C65
6D3E3C41636B6E6F776C65646765643E
313C2F41636B6E6F776C65646765643E
3C4163746976653E303C2F4163746976
653E3C41637475616C3E313C2F416374
75616C3E3C49443E373C2F49443E3C54
6578743E5C7864305C7865305C786534
5C7865305C7866305C7865645C786662
5C786535205C7865665C7866305C7865
655C7866365C7865355C7866315C7866
315C7865655C7866305C7866623A2074
657374202D205C7865645C7865355C78
6632205C7866315C7865355C7866325C
7865355C7865325C7865655C7865335C
786565205C7866315C7865655C786535
5C7865345C7865385C7865645C786535
5C7865645C7865385C7866663C2F5465
78743E3C54696D653E31333137383839
353839363835382E3030303030303030
30303030303C2F54696D653E3C2F656C
656D3E3C2F524F4F543E27
```

Вот скрины этих символов. И они же в HEX формате:

```
D19E030120
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее спасибо сенсеи по питону! =)

(Про парсер XML для меня отдельная тема, та еще  головная боль. Я уже задавал вопросы по ней, кому интересно можете у меня в профиле посмотреть).

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос данные из `print(data)` Просто, в том примере странные данные -- там несколько xml подряд и они сломаны, что странно. Лучше увидеть, что пришло к вам

Comment: Кст, у вас там есть строка `└ЁсшЄЁ юЄёюхфшэхэ` она означает `Арбитр отсоединен`: как это получить `print('└ЁсшЄЁ юЄёюхфшэхэ'.encode('cp866').decode('cp1251'))`. Судя по всему, вы текст ответа скопировали из консоли винды (думаю из cmd) на это указывает кодировка cp866. Я прав? Если да, то для чистоты эксперимента лучше еще выводить данные из сокета в файл: `open('log.txt', 'wb').write(data)` и открыть через нормальнйы редактор, например notepad++

Comment: Да, XML данные я тупо скопировал с консоли. Поэтому скорее всего консоль перекодировала. Я просто думал, что в консоли кодировка будет cp1251.

Comment: Добавил скриншоты с Notepad++. И строчку кода. В первом случае лог записан с включенным парсером, во-втором с отключенным.

Comment: Сейчас напишу код сервера, чтобы можно было проверить на мой код XML данные иммено в том виде, которые я получаю.

Comment: Вот так уже лучше :) Не знаю что за первые символы. Откройте в hex-редакторе, возможно там интересная последовательность, а именно длина xml-сообщения

Comment: Добавил пару скринов терминала IDE, при разных манипуляциях)

Comment: Нужно открыть hex-редактор и посмтреть на символы перед xml. В notepad++ он или встроенный, или есть для этого плагин. Либо, сделайте сами, например: `open('log_2.txt', 'wb').write(repr(data))`. Думаю, те первые байты будут теперь видны. Приложите содержимое log_2.txt в вопрос

Comment: Странно...хочу увидеть символы в notepad, притом что я отключил редактирование строки, но в notepad ничего не видно. Хотя в терминале отображается получение  этих символов.

Comment: @gil9red Странно получается. Ничего не делал, но в текстовый файл символы больше не сохраняются. Хотя в терминале отображаются. Я к посту добавлю эти символы в hex формате.

Comment: Пошаманил с парсером пока что. Взял Beautifulsoup4. Изменения добавил в код.

Comment: Смотрите, у вас в notepad++ те первые байты имеет  название `etx` `soh`, открываете вики https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII и смотрите `SOH  01  start of heading ` и `ETX  03  end of text `. Я ведь говорил, что они имеют смысл. Хотя мб и нет. Нужно в hex увидеть все сообщение, все что пришло от сервера, тогда проще будет угадывать. `D19E030120` -- что-то мне кажется что пробел (число 20) тут лишнее, т.к. первых байтов судя по скрину консолей было 4

Comment: Да, действительно...спасибо) затупил ( 
Тогда,можете подсказать, как можно сделать чтобы парсер не реагировал на эти символы? Есть идеи? ))

Comment: Легко, просто сначала 4 байта считайте из сокета, потом остальные

Comment: А важен ли порядок символов? просто получается  что на сокет приходят управляющие символы "конец текста ETX" и "начало заголовка SOH ", а это странно с точки зрения логики. Или как вообще в предыдущем примере EOT SOH NUL, что значит "конец передачи" и "начало заголовка" - тут конечно вопрос не к вам, а к тем кто ПО написал с которым я работаю)) просто мысли в слух

Comment: Добавил полный лог в HEX формате.

Comment: В том и то дело, что нужно знать структуру сообщений сервера, т.к. она может быть любой и те ascii символы могут означать не то, что в вики было написано. Что-то в hex не присланные данные пришли, сами посмотрите `b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251" ...` первые символы `b'` явно от результата `repr`, а не из сокета